# Watin Tests do not work on TeamCity build machine

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, teamcity, watin

I am running automated IE browser tests using Watin 2.1.0. They work correctly on my local machine however I am trying to get them to run on my TeamCity build machine but I get this error when the tests are run at the same particular point in each test:

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

The full stack trace:

```
at mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class.IHTMLWindow2_execScript(String code, String language)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEUtils.RunScript(String scriptCode, String language, IHTMLWindow2 window)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEUtils.RunScript(String scriptCode, String language, IHTMLWindow2 window)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEElement.GetJavaScriptElementReference()
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEFireEventHandler.CreateJavaScriptFireEventCode(NameValueCollection eventObjectProperties, String eventName)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEFireEventHandler.FireEvent(String eventName, NameValueCollection eventProperties, Boolean noWait)
   at WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEElement.FireEvent(String eventName, NameValueCollection eventProperties)
   at WatiN.Core.Element.FireEvent(String eventName, Boolean waitForComplete, NameValueCollection eventProperties)
   at WatiN.Core.Element.FireEvent(String eventName)
   at WatiN.Core.Element.Focus()
```

I'm not exactly sure whats going on here. The user account that the tests are being run on is an admin and I have set the sites used as trusted sites within the IE settings. I'm pretty sure its a setting in TeamCity that I have missed as they work locally but not on the TeamCity build server.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
We have three Team City agents running multiple projects with one as the host 
This is the Log On tab of one of the build agents that is not the host:

[image]

The "Allow service to interact with desktop" checkbox is ticked but the Watins still do not work.

On the host machine:

[image]

However the Watins do not work on this machine either. The Watins also run IE as a process using a different user account. So The build Agent runs under user account "A" and as part of the watin tests IE is run under a user account "B".

This information might be more relevant in finding a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the build agent service to "Allow service to interact with desktop" more than likely.

Comment: go to your service manager (start -> run -> services.msc) on the machine where the build agent is running.  find the "Team City Build Agent" service, open the properties.   on the "log on" tab, check off "allow service to interact with desktop", apply changes

Comment: The "Allow service to interact with desktop" was checked already. Do you mean un-check this?

Comment: no, meant to check it.   sounds like it might be something else, not sure what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

One of the MS updates a few months ago blocked access to run scripts hence why you are getting:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Check this chat [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1062093/installation-of-kb3025390-breaks-out-of-process-javascript-execution-in-ie11) that talks about that. This is one of those "fixes" that break things that have been running for years. You should find an alternative to using scripts (not always possible or as accurate as when running a script).

Comment: Thanks for the background on the issue, I had no idea this was the case. I did end up changing the test scripts. Originally I had been using SendKeys.SendWait(); to populate text fields and provide keystroke inputs but this caused issues. I replaced this by setting the text field value and manually firing the onChange event javascript method.

Comment: I've been doing the same for quite some time now because of this issue. Too bad MS "fixed" it :)